# Getting incorrect dates converting timestamp with new Date

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to convert timestamp to Date but I'm getting incorrect dates. I'm working on a project with Angular and Typescript.

I have timestamps like:
1451642400 (1st january 2016) and 1454320800 (1st february 2016)

If I code:

```
date = new Date(1451642400);
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
date = new Date(1454320800);
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
```

I get:
17/1/1970 20:14:02 and 17/1/1970 20:58:40

when I should get:
1/1/2016 10:00:00 and 1/2/2016 10:00:00

What's the problem? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to multiply your Unix Timestamp by 1000 so its in milliseconds..
If you do it like this, it will work:

```js
    date = new Date(1451642400 * 1000);
    console.log(date.toLocaleString());
    date = new Date(1454320800 * 1000);
    console.log(date.toLocaleString());
```

Answer (score 2):

The new Date()'s argument is in miliseconds. So try your timestamps with 1000 to make it in miliseconds.

var date = new Date(1451642400 * 1000);